# typescript type inferring started correctly then stops

Tags: typescript

I created a [typescript snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygChqgtmgLkTBFwCMUAnAbQF0BKRAbwFgAoRRAGxSkRxS4A3O04B3ABYwembHkQBefnjQA6NFOBZ6jAIQKl4ACYpgMMCiONWbdqM6J7nCAjRweqrnADmcwfRFbDgcAehDEFzAMRCNSNEVEakQARgAaRAAmWkCHRDCYuNVgOEoAUQBDCAlZRgUAPmY7IKbc-OdXdxRPHz9cAKc88IBffuCh9nHmoNBIWARkdCgM3sJiUgoaBkbgnj4BYXtJaRRZfYT9tQ0YLUwdRH1DMBMzCyttpoHItw8vX33Rz6uPixfAJJJpTLZAYgtTFMqVaq3RQNGwfIK5dpRTrdP54Ua5EY5RCTSbsIA) in typescript playground

[image]

```
function test(items: number[]) {
  let item;
  while((item = items.shift()) !== undefined) {


    
    console.log(item); // inferred as number

    // const dums = [ 1, 2];
    // dums.forEach(() => {




    //   console.log(item);
    // });
  }
}



function test2(items: number[]) {
  let item;
  while((item = items.shift()) !== undefined) {



    console.log(item); //inferred as number

    const dums = [ 1, 2];
    dums.forEach(() => {




      console.log(item); // typescript flag it as Variable 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    });
  }
}
```

The item object's type can be inferred as number at the beginning, and the type inferring stop in an function closure? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: It's a design limitation; see the linked duplicate and [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for details

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64408632/typescript-inconsistent-check-for-undefined-why-do-i-need-an-exclamation-poin

Comment: This is pretty simple test case, typescript should be able to do better than this.

Comment: "I don't think this question is duplicate": translating the answer there to here would be something like "your assignment to `item` narrows the apparent type from `any` to `number` via control flow analysis, but this does control flow analysis does not propagate into or out of function scopes, so inside the `forEach()` callback, `item` is seen as `any` and not `number`.  If you still don't think this is a duplicate you can vote to reopen it, but I'd expect any answer to be essentially a duplicate of that answer: it's a design limitation.

Comment: "Typescript should be able to do better than this" yeah, I hear you.  This is a very common pain point, but [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) explains what's going on.  In this case, [microsoft/TypeScript#35132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35132) and [microsoft/TypeScript#11498](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) might be a bit more targeted to this particular issue, and you can go there and  those and describe your use case if you think this should get addressed in a better way.

Comment: @jcalz It is wired, it is like, after you enter the first door, I know who you are, after you you enter the second door, I don't know who you are. Anyway, thanks